# calling C++ builder XE Form from delphi code

Tags: delphi, interop, c++builder

I'm using great TExceptionDialog from JEDI JCL package to show unhandled exceptions inside a C++ builder XE project, everything running ok so far. I've decided to enhance it a little bit by writing my own custom form to upload crash report to a server via FTP.

Problem is that I can't open my custom form from delphi PAS unit, tried to define as an external (no delphi programmer here, sorry :( ) but don't know how to properly code that. I've read lots of tutorials but couldn't find anything useful besides writing a DLL or an OLE container for my custom form, realy overkill for this project.

Question is, how can I properly execute this task? how to do ShowModal() of a form defined in a C++ unit, from a PAS delphi unit?

Comment: Can we be clear on the organisation. You have a Delphi .exe project which uses a C++ Builder .dll project?

Comment: It says there "inside a C++ builder XE project". Its a C++ Builder XE project which has a single form tracer.pas auto generated by JCL debug wizard. I need to call a ShowModal method of a form from that tracer.pas

Comment: Pass a method variable (`procedure of object`) to the form in `tracer.pas`. So, just like an event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you show me some code please? I'm not a Delphi programmer, I've tried that but I always have an "Unsatisfied forward or external declaration.." error. BTW, just to clarify myself, I have to call a ShowModal of a form outside that tracer.pas, which resides in a C++ file. Call should be inside tracer.pas.

Comment: Well, I don't know C++ Builder, so I don't know that side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easy and practical way of doing it, kinda ugly but works!

Trick is to get form by iterating thru all forms with Screen.Forms object. I've set TAG property for my form to a predefined number just to get an easy id of it.

In short, inside C++ unit of my form, I'll do this:

```
MyForm->Tag=9999; // easy way of Iding my form
```

Then, inside my delphi unit of TExceptionDialog, in SEND button click method:

```
procedure TExceptionDialog.SendBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: integer;
   form: TForm;
begin
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do // all forms
  begin
    form := Screen.Forms[i]; // get a form
    if(form.Tag = 9999) then // check if its my form
    begin
      form.ShowModal; // if its mine, call showmodal
      break;
    end;
  end;
  ModalResult := mrOk;  // return to my app
end;
```